# Is this an established phrase?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

> It would’ve guaranteed that he never again ***ate alone*** in Washington.

Does to *eat alone* have  idiomatic usage? Would like to see some established reference attesting to its meaning and usage.
The context of the article having this sentence suggests that to  *eat alone* means "to have no followers."

Comment: Why do think *eat alone* has an idiomatic meaning and doesn't simply mean dining alone?

Comment: I'm quoting from an article. The context is: If the person in question would have acted in a prudent manner, he wouldn't have had to *eat alone*.

Comment: If it's [John Gans' NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/18/opinion/john-bolton-book-trump.html), it seems to me it really does mean *dine alone* (as in "be without friends", which is possibly metaphorical, I suppose). Mr Gans does appear to [use the expression more than once](https://twitter.com/johngansjr/status/1224473563459010561). However, I don't think it has much to do with Twitter followers.

Comment: I think we're conflating terminology here. I take 'idiomatic usage' to mean 'common currency' but 'idiomatic meaning' to mean 'be an idiom' where an idiom is an established phrase deviating from normal grammaticality and/or using unusual / non-standard definition of one (or more) words. // I don't think 'ate [/eats...] alone' can be regarded as a fixed phrase. Yet. Although some metaphorical broadening (whether towards acceptability? friendship? _being surveilled_!?) is doubtless underway.

Comment: Yes, (1) by all accounts, it's not a fixed phrase and (2) Metaphorical extension is at play.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call this an idiomatic expression, but I've heard that phrase *never again eat alone* used to mean *this person is so popular that they can't even eat a meal without people wanting to be with them*.

Answer (score 0):

> Would like to see some established reference

You have given no source and no context - how authoritative do you want it to be?

There is an expression "to dine out on [a story/experience]", thus the implication is that the context described a remarkable experience and that, in the sense of the expression, people would invite him to dinner, etc., in order to hear the story. Thus he would not eat alone.

Comment: Thanks for bringing the expression *to dine out on [a story/experience]* to one's notice, and it may be distantly related to the context; but we are looking at something else

Comment: @Cosmopolitan What is the context? Who are "we"? PS, I have found the context, and it does fit.